# TypeLite in Net Core - does not add tt stuff

Tags: c#, typescript, .net-core, typelite

I've installed TypeLite in several Net Core projects (under VS) and it did not add tt stuff and Script folder etc.

When I used NET project then it did its job as expected.

Do I need to do it manually in Net Core project or I missed anything during installation/configuration stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately TypeLite doesn't support .NET Core. Support for .NET Core was planned for version 2.0, but it hasn't been released yet and it isn't even in the active development right now.